# generate strictly positive values using arima.sim in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am going to generate an `ARIMA(0, 1, 1)` series with 60 observations. I want them to be strictly positive for all moving average parameters (`ma`) while the series still follows an `ARIMA(0, 1, 1)` process. Can I do that using `arima.sim`?

```
arima.sim(n=100, model=list(ma=-0.9, order=c(0, 1, 1)))
```

This command give me both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample space of an ARIMA process is the whole real line, so it is impossible to guarantee that the simulated values will be positive.

You could just add a constant to all values to make them positive. Or could you take the exponential of the simulated values.

Comment: Thank you so much, if we add a constant, Do we still have the same process?